# webdriver :How to automate a page that appears sometimes in workflow?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm automating a workflow (survey) . This has few questions on each page.
Each page has few questions and a continue button .Depending on your answers next pages load. .How can I automate this scenario.

Comment: Create a class that resolves the type of page you are on, and then return that.

Comment: Apply all possible permutation combinations.Actually you are trying to automate MR surveys.It will be better if you already know the logic behind the scenarios then you can easily perform the task else use random permutations and combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**: **Selenium should only form a part of your automated testing strategy & it should be the smallest piece.** Test variations at a lower level instead.

---

If you want to ensure full coverage of all possibilities, you've two main options:

1. Test all variants through browser-based journey testing
2. Test variations outside of the browser & just use Selenium to check the higher-level wiring.

Option two is the way to go here — you want to ensure as much as possible is tested before the browser level.

This is often called the testing pyramid, as ideally you'll only have a small number of browser-based tests, with the majority of your testing done as unit or integration tests.

[image]

This will give you:

- **much better speed**, as you don't have the overhead of browser load to run each possible variant of your test pages.
- **better consistency**, i.e. with unit tests you know that they hold true for the code itself, whereas browser-based tests are dependent on a specific instance of the site being deployed (and so bring with it the other variations external to your code, e.g. environment configuration)

### Create minimal tests in Selenium to check the 'wiring'.

i.e. that submitting any valid values on page 1 gives *some* version of page 2 (but not testing what fields in particular are displayed).

### Test other elements independently at a lower level.

E.g. if you're following an MVC pattern:

- Test your controller class on it's own to see that with a given
  input, you get are sent to the expected destination & certain fields populated in the model.
- Test the view on it's own that given a certain model, it can display all the variations of the HTML, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to give if else statements and automate the same. Again it depends on how much scenarios u need to automate.